# Aggregation on the result of group

Tags: crossfilter

I have a data set as follows:
Year  |  Sale
2010  |  100
2011  |  60
2012  |  10
2013  |  1400
2010  |  900
2012  |  730
2014  |  300

First i want to group the value column by Year.so the result would be:
key   |  value
2010  |  1000
2011  |  60
2012  |  740
2013  |  1400
2014  |  300

and then i want diff of consecutive year as follows:
key   | value
2010  | 0
2011  | -940
2012  | -680
2013  | 660
2014  | -1100

can you help me do this in crossfilter reduce using add,redunce and initial methods

Comment: I want to do all the above in one add,reduce and initial method

Answer (score 0):

I'd strong recommend transforming your data before doing your Crossfilter so that each record includes the sales for the current and subsequent year. So you would have a record that looks like

```
Year | Sales | NextYearSales
2010 | 100   | 60
```

Then you can just do

```
var cf = crossfilter(data);
var dim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.Year });
var group = dim.group();
group.reduceSum(function(d) { return d.Sales - d.NextYearSales; });
```

Alternatively, you could use Crossfilter's [groupAll method](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-dimension_groupAll), or Reductio's [somewhat nicer wrapper](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio#aggregations-groupall-aggregations) of it.